# Amazon Order Fulfilment Feed

Tags: xml

I am submitting Amazon Order Fulfilment feed but it is giving me error.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>M_OT</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
  <AmazonOrderID>202-0001013-10110101</AmazonOrderID>
  <MerchantFulfillmentID>IW0000215462</MerchantFulfillmentID>
  <FulfillmentDate>2014-07-31T15:36:33-08:00</FulfillmentDate>
  <FulfillmentData>
    <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
    <ShippingMethod>Standard Delivery (3-5 days)</ShippingMethod>
    <ShipperTrackingNumber>201407310702</ShipperTrackingNumber>
  </FulfillmentData>
  <Item>
    <AmazonOrderItemCode>454334455454</AmazonOrderItemCode>
    <MerchantFulfillmentItemID>224634</MerchantFulfillmentItemID>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Item>
</OrderFulfillment>
 </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

but geting following error:

```
            <MessageID>1</MessageID>
            <ResultCode>Error</ResultCode>
            <ResultMessageCode>25</ResultMessageCode>
            <ResultDescription>We are unable to process the XML feed because one or                     more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed.
            </ResultDescription>
```

Can someone help me please...

Comment: Just validate your XML against their schema with any online/free XSD validator.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, Actually while writting the question, I mistakely removed a space before: xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd"> this. Otherwise the xml is 100% Valid. I already have checked it.

Comment: I've noticed you do not have an `encoding="utf-8"` attribute in your XML declaration. You will want that in there. Also, strip any BOM from the file. It still confuses some services/applications, although I would be surprised if that's the case with Amazon. If nothing works, their support will be the only ones who can help you I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks @MDeSchaepmeester, I had used encoding="utf-8" but it had given me same error. Also BOM?

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

1.) Your AmazonOrderID has too many numbers in it. It must match regex
    `\w{3}-\w{7}-\w{7}`.

2.) MerchantFulfillmentID cannot contain letters.
    It must match regex `\d{1,20}`.

3.) Your AmazonOrderItemCode has too
    many numbers in it. It must have exactly 14.